# asp.net how to get Response.Redirect url

Tags: asp.net

When debugging, how to check what has been set by Response.Redirect in ASP.NET 4.0 web application? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean set?  Are you referring to the query string?  You can always look at the Request object when you are debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Fiddler to watch the redirect.   It will show you exactly what the browser is getting from the server.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/